# Error while profilling & debugging a Java application simultaneoulsy using Dyna trace and :jdwp

Tags: java, debugging, dynatrace

While starting a Java application using the following JVM parameters along with a dyna trace agent :

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5000
-agentpath:c:\dynaTrace\agent\lib\dtagent.dll=name=abc,server=abc.com:9998"
```

I am getting an error `JDWP unable to get necessary JVMTI capabilities`

I tried searching few forums where it has been stated that it is not possible to do these two things simultaneously. Is it so ? I was also able to locate a java bug report which stated that JDWP: Loading twice is not properly handled.
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6354345
Is there a way to run these two things simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

For an exact answer I would need to know which JVM(Sun, IBM,..) you are running and also which Java version?
I know that for example the Sun JVM build versions 1.4.2_08, 1.4.2_11, 1.4.2_09, 1.4.2_15, 1.4.2_12 have troubles and bugs in the JVMTI implementation. Also some specific builds in the 1.5 and 1.6 Java.

Have you tried to update to the latest version of the Sun JVM?

Comment: Hi Klaus thanks for replying I am using java Hotspot JVM with version 1.6.45. And as much as i would love to switch to a newer version of sun JVM the client  business considerations prevents me from doing that :).